# How to capture the user of the active directory logged with Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I need to know what user of my Active Directory has started session in his machine because depending on which user is he can see a number of things or others.
The web app is hosted in an IIS server part of the domain

Any idea, please?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get this information from the client side only.

you should activate "windows authentication" on your site in the IIS, then you will have the user data available in your server.
you will have to expose a method on one of your controllers that will return the user information that you need.